# Continous function with non-zero derivate

Tags: calculus, functions

Is there a function $f(x)$, continous on some bounded interval $(a,b)$ such that for every $x \in (a,b)$ $f'(x)$ does exist and is not zero, and $f(x)$ is not injective?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

Comment: @Shadock I don't see the relevance. The OP requires $f$ to be differentiable.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood "OP" ?

Comment: @Shadock OP is a common abbreviation for "original poster" or "original post"

Comment: $f$ differentiable implies $f$ is continuous, so that assumption is not needed (nor is it used anywhere in the proof).

Comment: @DanielLittlewood to be non-differentiable in one point or more does not mean also that the derivate at this/these point/s not exist ?

Comment: @Shadock Excuse me? The two sentences "$f$ is differentiable at $x$" and "the derivative of $f$ exists at $x$" mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood english is not my mother tongue you may prefer if I say "non-derivatable" well I'm not sure that exist but anyway. I know that both means the same, what I was asking is that you said in your first comment "the OP requires f to be differentiable"...(well I do not see in the OP where it is written) and what I asked in my last comment is that "f'(x) does not exist" is obviously the case if we cannot calculate it. For me W-function on (1,2) is a function, continous on the bounded interval (1,2) such that f'(x) does not exist and is not zero. I do not see where I am wrong.

Comment: @Shadock Everything you say in your comment is correct. However, the OP states "... such that $f'(x)$ **does** exist" (my emphasis). In other words, he wants to be able to calculate the derivative at every point.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood oh gosh I haven't read that correctly... "rolleyes" ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u$ and $v$ be real numbers in the interval $(a,b)$ with $u\le v$

Suppose $u<v$ : The theorem of Rolle says that $f(u)=f(v)$ implies that there is a $w\in (u,v)$ with $f'(w)=0$ because $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$.

This is ruled out by the assumption. So, we get $u=v$, hence $f$ is injective.

Comment: Just rewrite that a little; $a,b$ already have a meaning in the problem.

Comment: Don't you need the assumption that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ (instead of just $(a,b)$ to be able to apply Rolle's theorem?

Comment: I edited the answer. $u$ and $v$ must be in the interval $(a,b)$. The values $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ can be anything. But on $(a,b)$, $f$ must be injective.